# Dropdown list not sending SelectedIndex back to server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

This is an odd one. I have a very simple page with a few labels and a single Dropdown List control. This control is an ASP: control. When the user clicks on one of the items in the list, the value selected is not passed back to the server at all. I've tried everything. `Enableviewstate`, `AutoPostBack` (sets the index back to 0), an `UpdatePanel`, and an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event (never fires).

I know how this control is supposed to work. While not an ASP.NET expert by any stretch, I've got a good handle on all this. I've never seen a control that didn't fire its event(s) or sent its new value back to the server.

The control is not databound. Rather, it's filled manually within a `foreach`:

```
myControl.Items.Add(new ListItem(etc, etc, etc));
```

Control markup

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="labelDisp" 
                  ID="accountInfoList" 
                  runat="server" 
                  EnableViewState="true" 
                  autopostback="true" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="accountInfoList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Control code-behind

```
if (lstAccounts != null && !Page.IsPostBack) { 
    AccountInfo acctInfo = lstAccounts[0]; 
    PopulateFormData(lstAccounts); 
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with `PostBack and IsPostBack` where is the code where you are actually calling the OnSelectedIndexChange Event.. explaining how things are filled or not filled helps nobody so please show all relevant code.. this is actually not that trivial and there are also TONS of Working examples on how to do this.. fyi also if it's not hitting your event.. make sure to double check the AutoPostBack property and set it = true... and then in your code on the Page_Load event you may need to add some `if(IsPostBack){} or the opposite if(!IsPostback){}`

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you're reloading the items in the list by executing your foreach loop on every postback. This would certainly cause this behaviour.

Comment: Pleas show all relevant code...!!!

Comment: Right. There is a !Page.Postback in the Load_Page event that prevents the DDL from being reloaded on a PostBack. That's why it's so screwy. I know that the control is not being reloaded on Postback. That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: I have a conference call. I'll add the code after that. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, the code for the control:                  <asp:DropDownList CssClass="labelDisp" ID="accountInfoList" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="accountInfoList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                      </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: And the codebehind in the Page_Load event:                 if (lstAccounts != null && !Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    AccountInfo acctInfo = lstAccounts[0];
                    PopulateFormData(lstAccounts);
                }

Comment: I apologize for the lack of formatting. I don't know how to get it to come out right. I just joined here today. This is my first thread.

Comment: Where is the event handle: accountInfoList_SelectedIndexChanged in your code? Also, are you using AJAX? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Without your code it is quite difficult to verify, but an alternative would be through `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

It has to do with .Value. If there is more than one ListItem whose .Value is the same, only the first one will be selected. And since .Value didn't change from the initial SelectedIndex, no postback was done.

I happened to recall this because someone had mentioned it in passing a couple months ago. Naturally, no exception is thrown.

When I ask another question sometime, I'll try and provide all the info in the proper format. Thanks to those of you who replied.